# InvalidResourceRequestException Yarn Exception while running Spark in Cluster mode with yarn in hadoop 2.4

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Using `Apache spark 1.1.0` with `hadoop 2.4`

Also my `cluster is on CDH 5.1.3`

I tried with below command to start `spark with yarn`.

```
./spark-shell --master yarn 
./spark-shell --master yarn-client
```

I got the following exception:

> 14/10/15 21:33:32 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application
>   report from ASM:
>            appMasterRpcPort: 0
>            appStartTime: 1413388999108
>            yarnAppState: RUNNING
>
> 14/10/15 21:33:44 ERROR cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Yarn
>   application already ended: FAILED
>
> ======Node manager Exception ============================================
>
> Caused by:
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidResourceRequestException):
>   Invalid resource request, requested memory < 0, or requested memory >
>   max configured, requestedMemory=1408, maxMemory=1024  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerUtils.validateResourceRequest(SchedulerUtils.java:228)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMServerUtils.validateResourceRequests(RMServerUtils.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService.allocate(ApplicationMasterService.java:444)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.allocate(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationMasterProtocol$ApplicationMasterProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationMasterProtocol.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1026)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1986)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1982)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1980)
>
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1410)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1363)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
>     at $Proxy11.allocate(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.allocate(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.java:77)
>     ... 20 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your YARN Configuration, the maximum memory an application can request for a container is 1024MB. But the spark client is requesting a container with 1408MB. Either change the config file for spark to request less RAM or raise the max memory in YARN.

Comment: Yes. These two are the configurations to adjust: 
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb